# Does Docker use different tools to run containers on different Operating Systems?

Tags: docker

I am studying the course "Docker Essentials: A Developer Introduction" in "cognitiveclass.ai" and one of the questions was "What tool makes it possible to run Docker containers on operating systems other than Linux?" and the choices where: LinuxByte, OSContainers, Docker Swarm and Linuxkit.
But no matter how much I looked for the answer I couldn't find anything that explain this problem clearly.

I know that Docker Swarm is a tool for managing a cluster of container, also Docker uses Linux virtual machine to run containers on mac and hyper-v for windows.

Answer (score 10):

Its Linuxkit. Docker containers are based on linux containers, so you need to have linux to run them. Linuxkit came as a solution for that.

Read [this](https://www.cio.com/article/3190937/linux/what-is-linuxkit-and-why-does-it-matter.html) article to get some idea.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it's Linuxkit, when I read I thought it was only for customizing Linux.